# Python file browsing

Tags: python

I can browse folder and files in python but when i selected the file there is no change. I just want to paste the folder or file path in my code. For example,

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkTeal2")
layout = [[sg.T("")], [sg.Text("Choose a file: "), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse(key="-IN-")], [sg.Button("Submit")]]

###Building Window
window = sg.Window('My File Browser', layout, size=(600, 150))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break
    elif event == "Submit":
        import sys
        sys.stdout = open('../pythonProject3/hedef_dosya.txt', 'w')
        print(values["-IN-"])
        sys.stdout.close()
```

I want to use the selection in this another .py file

```
def import_data():
    data = pd.read_csv('x.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: Content of `sg.Input` and `sg.FileBrowse` changed after file selected and OK, txt file changed after "Submit" event.

Comment: I can not explain my question, the txt file changes but I want to use the data(path) in txt file which is selected in my other python code how can I merge(?) them.

Comment: So when I select the file, it will be write on 'x.csv' part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to quit GUI window and save the results to a CSV file, then another script.

With `io.StringIO` as buffer, then convert it to `DataFrame` from string directly.

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg


sg.theme("DarkTeal2")
layout = [
    [sg.T("")],
    [sg.Text("Choose a file: "),
     sg.Input(), sg.FilesBrowse(key="-IN-")],
    [sg.Button("Submit")],
]

window = sg.Window('My File Browser', layout, size=(600, 150))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break
    elif event == "Submit":
        """ Files in Horizontal """
        buffer = StringIO(values["-IN-"])
        df = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=";", header=None)
        """ Files in Vertical
        string = '\n'.join(values['-IN-'].split(";"))
        buffer = StringIO(string)
        df = pd.read_csv(buffer, header=None)
        """
        print(df)

window.close()
```

Horizontal Output

```py
                              0   ...                                13
0  C:/Software/Python/python.exe  ...  C:/Software/Python/pythonw_d.pdb

[1 rows x 14 columns]
```

Vertical Output

```py
                                    0
0       C:/Software/Python/python.exe
1       C:/Software/Python/python.pdb
2     C:/Software/Python/python_d.exe
3     C:/Software/Python/python_d.pdb
4      C:/Software/Python/python3.dll
5    C:/Software/Python/python3_d.dll
6     C:/Software/Python/python39.dll
7     C:/Software/Python/python39.pdb
8   C:/Software/Python/python39_d.dll
9   C:/Software/Python/python39_d.pdb
10     C:/Software/Python/pythonw.exe
11     C:/Software/Python/pythonw.pdb
12   C:/Software/Python/pythonw_d.exe
13   C:/Software/Python/pythonw_d.pdb
```

Comment: when I edit my code with your help can not read anything (exit code 0) also submit button useless

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [C:/Users/90543/PycharmProjects/demand/x.csv]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0  
I just want to read this x.csv but i cant reach

Comment: One more option `header=None` added when `pd.read_csv` for no header here, update code.

Comment: same can not reading the data, console gives me the browsed path :(

Comment: Your code or my code ? Add one more statement `print(df)` to show the result after `read_csv`.

Comment: done, its useful thanks.